# Validating Base Number

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that checks a positive integer number against a base value, and returns True if all digits of the number are strictly less than base, and false otherwise. Some of the outputs I have achieved are:

```
    >>> base_and_number(12345, 2)
    False
    >>> base_and_number(12345, 8)
    True
    >>> base_and_number(9, 5)
    False
    >>> base_and_number(10110, 2)
    True
```

These are definitely correct, and I've made this code to be sure of it. The issue is that I'm not sure if I'm approaching it the best way, as I want to find a much more efficient way to evaluate to validate Base-n numbers. Here it is:

```
    def base_and_num(number, base):
        int_list = []
        for digit in str(number):
            int_list.append(int(digit))

        result = []
        for i in range(len(int_list)):
            if int_list[i] < base:
                result.append(int_list[i])

        if len(result) == len(str(number)):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Is there a much easier way to do this? I feel that there is a much more obvious method to doing this but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is:

```
def base_and_num(number, base):
    for i in str(number):
        if base <= int(i):
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert it and see if it fails.

```
try:
    int(str(number), base)
except ValueError:
    print('{} is invalid base for {}'.format(base, number))
```

Demo:

```
>>> number = 456
>>> base = 7
>>> int(str(number), base)
237
>>> base = 3
>>> int(str(number), base)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 3: '456'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
def basecheck(number,base):
   return all([int(x) < base for x in str(number)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use comprehension list to simplify your code :

```
 def base_and_num(number, base):
     return all([str(base)>digit for digit in str(number)])
```

using the fact that ascii order is compatible with natural order.

Answer (score 1):

Well..

```
def base_and_num(number, base):
    return all(int(digit) < base for digit in str(number))
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to stay a bit true to **your** code (I'd do that with a `reduce`, but, oh well, I don't think we should explain that approach here).

Yes, there is; first of all, your `else: continue` is redundant. You can just omit it.

I'd say, `return False` as soon as you meet your first digit greater than `base`. And if you didn't return `False`, `return True`. Something like

```
def base_and_num(number, base):
    number = int(number) ## making sure we don't break on floats, strings etc.
    while number != 0:
        digit = number % 10 #modulo
        if digit > base:
            return False #function exits here!
        number = number / 10 #integer division
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a full fledged answer, but rather a tip which should allow you to arrive at a better answer on your own.

1. You don't need the extra integer list, you can directly iterate through a string in python.
2. Return false as soon as you come across a digit not fulfilling your criteria. If there is none, return true.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to let Python do the work for you. Convert the number to a string, then try to convert it back to an integer using the specified base. Python will throw a `ValueError` if any digit equals or exceeds the base.

```
def base_and_number(number, base):
    try:
        int(str(number), base)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

This works with negative integers as well as positive ones, which the answers strictly comparing individual digits will not.